# Mediawiki get Content from one page to another

Tags: mediawiki

I searched way too long to find an answer to this problem, but I keep finding the wrong things.
My problem is I need to extract content from page A by writing code on page B.
So, for example, I have Page A with the content:

> here is some text

and on page B my code is something like:

> getcontent(Page A)

and it shows:

> here is some text

Obviously I will work with that output, but for now, I just need to transfer the content.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Templates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates) do this, and there are a number of more complicated options as well. It really depends on the details of what you need.

Comment: Page A can't be a template, is there a way to do it with them anyways or is this what you meant

Comment: To elaborate on the problem. I need Page B to get the content from some pages in my wiki and give them to my Lua script(scribunto) which will work with them

Comment: That's not really any more specific. Are you looking for [`Title:getContent()`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto/Lua_reference_manual#Title_objects)?

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by [Tgr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323407) in comments and it was [`Title:getContent()`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto/Lua_reference_manual#Title_objects).

Answer (score 0):

You can transclude a page with the same syntax as a template call, just put a `:` before the page title (that represents "main namespace"):

in page B:

> {{:Page A}}

Comment: Still, thanks, even though I already implemented the other way it may help anyone looking for something similar.